# Unibill, testing iOS In App Purchases & Unity

Tags: ios, ipad, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

Big headache! I cannot get IAP to work on my iPad device.

1. I have created a developer account on iTunes.
2. I created some app information, SKU etc., without uploading a binary.
3. I have set up Unibill to use the bundle identifiers and Ids as shown in the iTunes dashboard.
4. I logged out of existing users on the iPad.
5. I created a test user with a new email.
6. I fooled around with Xcode settings, trying a million different settings, but mainly following the documentation best I could: specifically, linking the Storekit library.

Unibill initialization keeps returning a 'CRITICAL_ERROR'. Maybe it's a Unibill problem, but what could I have forgotten?

Does testing In-App Purchases require a special contract type?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not the fault of Unibill. There are too many reason for the failure of IAP test. Basically, you can have a look at this [check list](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/) first. Follow the questions could solve for most situation.

But there is something not correct in that checklist, the most important one is you do not need to upload the binary.

For your situation, I suggest you check the following things:

1. If you can create the IAP product, so it seems your contract is OK. IAP need a valid paid contract and correct bank information. So you can check if your bank information is correct or not.
2. Did you try to uninstall the app in your device and install it again? The old one would not be luck.
3. Did you generate and use new provision file for the build? Maybe old one does not contain the IAP feature.
4. Check your app id, version and build version. They should be all set properly or the IAP won't work.

Hope it can help.